# Auto-Fill Form Fields in Facebook In-App Browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My web-based form has common field names such as first-name, last-name, and email. In a mobile browser, the user is prompted to autofill the fields correctly. When a user clicks a link inside of the facebook app to launch the in-app web browser to visit my page, the Autofill does not work for most of the fields. It only works for the email address field. Is there some field tagging method that I can use to indicate to facebook that autofill should be used?

Answer (score 0):

The other fields needs to be mapped to autocomplete. E.g., first and last name autocomplete values `given-name` and `family-name` respectively.

```
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" autocomplete="given-name" />

<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" autocomplete="family-name" />
```

There are more fields such as phone number that can also be mapped and works with the FB in-app browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete